# Error while opening pdf file that was converted from binary data using File.WriteAllBytes in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using File.WriteAllbytes to convert binary data to pdf/RTF/Doc/Docx etc., Except pdf other files I can view by open. But while opening pdf file from windows explorer, i got error like "There was an error opening this document. This file is damaged and could not be opened."
I'm using following code.

```
if (!dbReader.IsDBNull(o))
   bytedata = (byte[])dbReader["resume"];
  if (!dbReader.IsDBNull(1))
   extension = dbReader.GetString(1);

  try
  {
   var filePath = "C:\Data\a.pdf";
   File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytedata);
```

Can you please let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: Your bytes are damaged.  Check the code that put them into the DB.

Comment: Your file contains all the bytes of dbReader["resume"]. I think that for a PDF/RTF/Doc/Docx you need to wrap it in a special way (for example a header)

Comment: Am not sure about this but you may not be reading the bytes completely with that `cast`.. you should use [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx) method

Comment: @Aniruth: what is the syntax for using GetBytes()?

Comment: @user2960882 See [this](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1123-reading-blob-data-from-database.aspx) example

Comment: @SLaks: But this is working fine for RTF/Doc and Docx.

Answer (score 0):

There are all manner of things that can cause the error you're seeing.  Your best bet would be to look at the bytes that were written and compare them with the actual data.  First check should be "is there the same number of bytes in each?" then worry about the content.  PDF is very much an offset-based format and if extra data is injected or left out, you will be damaging the file (for example, changing line-termination discipline, which almost assuredly is **not** what's happening here).

If you are not reading the entirety of the data, you will be leaving out the cross-reference table either in whole or in part and that takes a lot to recover from.

One reason other file formats appear to be reading correctly is that the file sizes might be under buffer sizes and your PDFs are longer.